# ajax listener not called for component in datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, myfaces, tomahawk

The ajax listener is not called for a checkbox that is in a datatable.
I reduced the problematic code to the following simple (and not very meaningful) example.

I have a datatable and in every row a checkbox. By clicking the checkbox the ajax listener shall be called but it isn't called. I have also a checkbox outside the datatable. When clicking this checkbox the ajax listener is called.
What is wrong with the checkboxes in the datatable or what should I do to get it working?

Here is the xhtml file (I'm using tomahawk):

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAssignmentOutside" value="#{myController.assignments[100000]}">
        <f:ajax render="selectionStateOutside" listener="#{myController.processAjaxBehavior}"/>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:outputText id="selectionStateOutside" value="#{myController.assignments[100000] ? 'selected' : 'not selected'}"/>

    <p/>

    <t:dataTable id="assignmentsTable" value="#{myController.allEntities}" var="row" forceIdIndexFormula="#{row.id}" preserveDataModel="false">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{row.id}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAssignment" value="#{myController.assignments[row.id]}">
                <f:ajax render="selectionState" listener="#{myController.processAjaxBehavior}"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText id="selectionState" value="#{myController.assignments[row.id] ? 'selected' : 'not selected'}"/>
        </h:column>
    </t:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

the controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyController
{
    private List<Entity> entities;
    private Map<Long, Boolean> assignments;

    public Map<Long, Boolean> getAssignments() {
        if (assignments == null) {
            assignments = new HashMap<>();
            assignments.put( 100000L, true );
            assignments.put( 100001L, true );
            assignments.put( 100002L, false );
            assignments.put( 100003L, false );
        }
        return assignments;
    }

    public List<Entity> getAllEntities() {
        entities = new ArrayList<>();
        entities.add( new Entity( 100000L ));
        entities.add( new Entity( 100001L ) );
        entities.add( new Entity( 100002L ) );
        entities.add( new Entity( 100003L ) );
        return entities;
    }

    public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("#### processAjaxBehavior");
        // here some things should be done in model
        // and the component re-rendered by ajax component shows the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Best practice dictates that you shouldn't be performing business logic in the getter. Then you want to confirm there's no silent conversion/validation error causing the request to choke (look in your JS console)

Comment: There are no errors in firefox web console. Clicking on a checkbox (no matter if inside or outside the datatable) let the JSF request run through all phases, including INVOKE_APPLICATION (checked with a PhaseListener).

Comment: At face value, nothing seems to be wrong with your setup. Try changing the name of your ajax method (and removing the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` parameter. What version of JSF are you running?

Comment: I tried several method signatures without success. But I found the reason, it's the forceIdIndexFormula attribute of tomahawks datatable which has a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1663). Without this attribute set it generates the id "j_idt32:assignmentsTable:0:selectionState", with it "j_idt32:assignmentsTabl100000:selectionState" (instead of "j_idt32:assignmentsTable:100000:selectionState").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomahawk's datatable has a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1663) in generating the client id if the attribute "forceIdIndexFormula" is set.
After removing the attribute "forceIdIndexFormula" from "t:datatable" it works as expected.